how to add multi vf filter on one command ffmpeg
can you help me
i need scale video to 720p and add drawtext watermark
i tray this put not work
-filter:v scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 28 -b:v 1.5M -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -vf "drawtext=text='✠ Orsozox Movies ✠':x=w-tw-10:y=10:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=5:shadowy=5" -c:a aac -b:a 128k

I also face a problem sometimes it works but I face a problem with the stream when uploading to Telegram on some mobile devices the video does not work on them

Start with -vf followed by all filters. Seperate filters with a comma (,) and no spaces. Finally, add your encoding parameters and encode. Also, if working with multiple inputs use -filter_complex instead of -vf.

thank you
can you add example or solve my code

... -filter:v "scale=-2:720, drawtext=tex..." ...

thank you code work very good
